A problem occurred evaluating project ':unityLibrary'
After updating the Unity Purchasing plugin to 4.12.2, we are experiencing the following build issue,
A problem occurred evaluating project ':unityLibrary'.

Could not find method afterEvaluate() for arguments [build_b4cvnstzoh86pqopi2sr3nm85$_run_closure3@217f77b, build_b4cvnstzoh86pqopi2sr3nm85$_run_closure4@62d8e6dc] on project ':unityLibrary' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

here is our Unity generated maintemplate.gradle file.
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
**DEPS**}

android {
    namespace "com.unity3d.player"
    ndkPath "**NDKPATH**"
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = **BUILTIN_NOCOMPRESS** + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**
}
**IL_CPP_BUILD_SETUP**
**SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**


We have tried upgrading Unity to 2022.3.39f1 and updating the Firebase plugins, but the error persists. If we downgrade the Unity Purchasing Plugin, everything works fine, but we cannot do that because Android requires an upgrade to the billing library before August 31st.
